# Is this a bug in gcc 11.2.1 related to _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI?

Tags: c++, string, c++11, gcc, centos7

The following C++ code fails to compile on gcc 11.2.1 on CentOS 7.2.2009 (available through [Software Collections](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/) only) using the following command :

**Command** : `scl enable devtoolset-11 'g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -o test'`

**Code** :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {

        std::string s="abcdefg";
        s.erase(s.cbegin(), s.cend());
        return 0;
}
```

**Error**:

```
test.cpp: In function 'int main()':
test.cpp:7:16: error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_string<char>::erase(std::basic_string<char>::const_iterator, std::basic_string<char>::const_iterator)'
    7 |         s.erase(s.cbegin(), s.cend());
      |         ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /opt/rh/devtoolset-11/root/usr/include/c++/11/string:55,
                 from /opt/rh/devtoolset-11/root/usr/include/c++/11/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /opt/rh/devtoolset-11/root/usr/include/c++/11/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /opt/rh/devtoolset-11/root/usr/include/c++/11/ios:42,
                 from /opt/rh/devtoolset-11/root/usr/include/c++/11/ostream:38,
                 from /opt/rh/devtoolset-11/root/usr/include/c++/11/iostream:39,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/opt/rh/devtoolset-11/root/usr/include/c++/11/bits/basic_string.h:4766:7: note: candidate: 'std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::erase(std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>; std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type = long unsigned int]'
 4766 |       erase(size_type __pos = 0, size_type __n = npos)
      |       ^~~~~
/opt/rh/devtoolset-11/root/usr/include/c++/11/bits/basic_string.h:4766:23: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::basic_string<char>::const_iterator' to 'std::basic_string<char>::size_type' {aka 'long unsigned int'}
 4766 |       erase(size_type __pos = 0, size_type __n = npos)
      |             ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~
/opt/rh/devtoolset-11/root/usr/include/c++/11/bits/basic_string.h:4783:7: note: candidate: 'std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::iterator std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::erase(std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::iterator) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>; std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::iterator = std::basic_string<char>::iterator]'
 4783 |       erase(iterator __position)
      |       ^~~~~
/opt/rh/devtoolset-11/root/usr/include/c++/11/bits/basic_string.h:4783:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
/opt/rh/devtoolset-11/root/usr/include/c++/11/bits/basic_string.h:4803:7: note: candidate: 'std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::iterator std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::erase(std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::iterator, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::iterator) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>; std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::iterator = std::basic_string<char>::iterator]'
 4803 |       erase(iterator __first, iterator __last);
      |       ^~~~~
/opt/rh/devtoolset-11/root/usr/include/c++/11/bits/basic_string.h:4803:22: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from '__normal_iterator<const char*,[...]>' to '__normal_iterator<char*,[...]>'
 4803 |       erase(iterator __first, iterator __last);
      |             ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
```

The error means that the compiler is unable to find the method `std::string::erase(const_iterator, const_iterator)`, which should have been available in C++11 (as per [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase) reference).

The same code compiles fine on other OS's using same version of gcc (e.g. [here](https://godbolt.org/z/E194Meo4G))

I was able to track down the reason for this difference in behaviour to the definition of compiler macro `_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI` in CentOS vs other distributions. Most distribution enable `_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI` while CentOS forcefully disables it as described [here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1546704). See more about the macro [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_dual_abi.html).

My current understanding of the macro `_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI` is this :

- In gcc 5 onwards, there were changes in the ABI of `std::basic_string` introduced due to [Copy-On-Write](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) not being allowed in C++11.
- However, this should not change the API's that were promised to be available with C++11.
- So, `std::basic_string::erase(const_iterator, const_iterator)` should be available irrespective of which ABI I choose.

However, what I am observing is that the method `std::basic_string::erase(const_iterator, const_iterator)` is simply not available in the older ABI (i.e. when `_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0`.

Is this a bug in gcc, or is there something wrong in my understanding of the macro `_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI` ?

Comment: `.erase()` with const iterators is a [C++11 feature](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase). Makes sense that it's not allowed with a pre-C++11 abi.

Comment: From the github mirror it seems this overload should be available regardless - https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/releases/gcc-11.2.0/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/basic_string.h#L1864. You should probably check if your `/opt/rh/devtoolset-11/root/usr/include/c++/11/bits/basic_string.h` contains it at all, maybe they also provide older libstdc++ with newer compiler for backward compatibility?

Comment: @dewaffled Note the macro `_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI` on line 64. `erase` with const iterators is defined only if this macro is 1. There are two class definitions of std::basic_string, the other one (for older ABI support) is defined when `_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0`: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/releases/gcc-11.2.0/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/basic_string.h#L3173. This one does not have the erase method with const iterators.

Comment: @johngreen Indeed, missed that bit. Looks like a bug then. They even have `replace(const_iterator __i1, const_iterator __i2` with `#if __cplusplus >= 201703L` guard in that part but not `erase` overload.